# Will default methods in Spring Data repositories hit caches on other methods?

Tags: java, spring, caching, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Will default methods in Spring Data repositories hit caches on other methods within the same repository?

For example, will a call to this method:

```
default Long findIdByCodeRequired(final String code) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(code)) {
        throw new DataCheckException(MSG_CODE_REQUIRED, getEntityMessageArgument());
    }
    return findIdByCode(code).orElseThrow(notFound(code));
}
```

Hit the cache on this method?

```
@Cacheable("codeType-findIdByCode")
@Query("select c from #{#entityName} c " //
        + "where c.code = :code")
Optional<Long> findIdByCode(String code);
```

Or do default methods not go through the proxy necessary for the caching to work?

Comment: Have you tried it? How comes there is doubt about the result?

Comment: the code runs fine, but I'm not sure how to confirm/deny that it is hitting the cache and was wondering if anyone else had figured it out.
The doubt is due to other patterns like `@Async` on `@Component` classes not working if you call within the component. Spring needs to hit the generated proxy for the component to get the `@Async` to work and calling methods within the component does not hit the proxy. I'm not sure if this applies here since the repositories use a different code generation mechanism than components.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is "no, default methods in a repository will not hit the cache on other methods"

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testContactTypeCaching() {
        System.out.println("first call to findIdByCode");
        contactTypeRepo.findIdByCode("MOBILE");
        System.out.println("second call to findIdByCode");
        contactTypeRepo.findIdByCode("MOBILE");
        System.out.println("third call to findIdByCode");
        contactTypeRepo.findIdByCode("MOBILE");
    
        System.out.println("first call to getReferenceByCodeRequired");
        contactTypeRepo.getReferenceByCodeRequired("MOBILE");
        System.out.println("second call to getReferenceByCodeRequired");
        contactTypeRepo.getReferenceByCodeRequired("MOBILE");
        System.out.println("third call to getReferenceByCodeRequired");
        contactTypeRepo.getReferenceByCodeRequired("MOBILE");
    }
```

Output:

```
first call to findIdByCode
Hibernate: 
    select
        contacttyp0_.ct_id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        contact_types contacttyp0_ 
    where
        contacttyp0_.code=?
second call to findIdByCode
third call to findIdByCode

first call to getReferenceByCodeRequired
Hibernate: 
    select
        contacttyp0_.ct_id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        contact_types contacttyp0_ 
    where
        contacttyp0_.code=?
second call to getReferenceByCodeRequired
Hibernate: 
    select
        contacttyp0_.ct_id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        contact_types contacttyp0_ 
    where
        contacttyp0_.code=?
third call to getReferenceByCodeRequired
Hibernate: 
    select
        contacttyp0_.ct_id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        contact_types contacttyp0_ 
    where
        contacttyp0_.code=?
```