# How do you get default methods in Spring Data repositories to hit the cache?

Tags: java, caching, proxy, spring-data-jpa

This is related to this question, which shows that default methods in Spring Data repositories do not hit the cache:
[Will default methods in Spring Data repositories hit caches on other methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180483/will-default-methods-in-spring-data-repositories-hit-caches-on-other-methods)

I have this cached method:

```
    @Cacheable("codeType-findIdByCode")
    default Long findIdByCodeRequired(final String code) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(code)) {
            throw new DataCheckException(MSG_CODE_REQUIRED, getEntityMessageArgument());
        }

        return findIdByCode(code).orElseThrow(notFound(code));
    }
```

And I want this default method to hit the cache:

```
    default T getReferenceByCodeRequired(final String code) {
        return getOne(findIdByCodeRequired(code));
    }
```

Note that I tried this mechanism and it did not work:

```
    default T getReferenceByCodeRequired(final String code) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final CodeTypeRepository<T> codeTypeRepo = (CodeTypeRepository<T>) AopContext.currentProxy();
        return getOne(codeTypeRepo.findIdByCodeRequired(code));
    }
```

How can I get it to hit the cache without moving the default method out of the repository.

Reasons for keeping it in the repository: its a parent repository of a fair number of child repositories. A service method version of getReferenceByCodeRequired would need to take in the child repository itself in order to compose the two repository calls (`findIdByCodeRequired` and `getOne`)

Also, I don't want to put @Cacheable on the `getReferenceByCodeRequired` method as I'm trying to avoid caching entities.